# sql query to show matrix of each year an employee was working for the company

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, prepared-statement

Data

[image]

expected Output

[image]

write a script that will create a matrix (expected output) with years on the x-axis and employee id on the y-axis. The purpose of this matrix is to show each year an employee was working for the company.
Guidelines:
-   The script should be dynamic and no hard coded values are allowed. 
-   If we add more data to the table, the script should automatically pick that up and expand the matrix accordingly. 
-   The matrix should always display the data till the current year + 1. So for example, the current year now is 2016 and the matrix should extend till 2017. 
-   For employees that are still active, they will show as active for all the future years.

above is the problem.First image is data and second image is expected output

I am a beginner to sql. Any help is appreciated. I have been trying this for 2 days but could got no luck!!

Comment: Try pivot query

Comment: You need to show us some effort in order to get meaningful help.  Few people are going to bang out an entire query for you.  And by the way, are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They are very different databases.

Comment: You have to do pivot

Comment: Check this post..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932321/matrix-result-using-sql-server-2008-r2/25932754#25932754

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.a
(
    Emp_id INT, 
    HireDate DATE, 
    TerminateDate DATE
);

INSERT dbo.a SELECT 1, '2012-01-01', '2018-01-04'
UNION  ALL    SELECT 2, '2012-01-02', '2022-01-07';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT Emp_id';

;WITH dr AS
(
SELECT MinDate = MIN(HireDate),
     MaxDate = MAX(TerminateDate)
FROM dbo.a
),
n AS
(
 SELECT 
 TOP (DATEDIFF(Year, (SELECT MinDate FROM dr), (SELECT MaxDate FROM dr)) + 
 1)
 d = DATEADD(Year, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1, 
 (SELECT MinDate FROM dr))
 FROM sys.all_objects
  )
 SELECT @sql += ',
 ' + QUOTENAME(year(d)) + ' = CASE WHEN ''' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), d, 120) 
 + ''' BETWEEN HireDate AND TerminateDate THEN ''1'' ELSE '''' END' FROM n;

 SELECT @sql += ' FROM dbo.a;'

- -print @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.a;
```

Comment: Its my first time for post answer om stack overflow .

Comment: plase add some explanations to improve your answer quality.

Comment: Over here we are first get the min and max year then use using case to check the year is in min or max then 1 .